# Oracle BPM Suite 12c

Tags: oracle, business-process-management

I'm beginner in Oracle BPM Suite and i want use this 12c
when go to download page
i see this messages :

This page contains the download for evaluating Oracle BPM Suite and includes only the generic quick start install. You can download other options from our Oracle Software Delivery Cloud.

Please visit the Fusion Middleware: Download, Installation & Configuration Readme Files and theInstallation Guide for Oracle SOA and BPM Suite for an overview of the full production installation process and the Certification Guide for platform specific information.
The download on this page is called the BPM Suite Quick Start Installation.  Please note that quick start installation files are different for BPM Suite and SOA Suite.  For the download below, please follow the steps outlined in the Installing SOA Suite and Business Process Management Suite Quick Start for Developers Guide to set up a development or evaluation environment for Oracle BPM Suite.

and downloaded this Product but note :
The generic BPM Suite Quick Start Installer for developers is used on all platforms. It allows you to install a development or evaluation environment quickly on a single host computer. It includes Oracle BPMN Suite, Oracle SOA Suite, Oracle JDeveloper, and integrated WebLogic Server and Evaluation Database.

what's different between BPM Suite Quick Start (development or evaluation environment) and Oracle BPM Suite (Server deition for Product environment )

please help me...

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the *Oracle Business Process Management Suite Quick Start distribution* allows you to quickly install a development environment on a single host computer suitable for testing purpose. If you want to setup the BPM domain on production servers you can checkout he official [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/INSOA/planning.htm#INSOA352)

If you don`t have time to install the BPM domain to your environment you can use the official prebuilt virtual machine for developers by Oracle 
[from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html)